# events not rendering http.post, no console errors @fullcalendar/angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have seen all other posts about this problem
I am trying to populate full calendar with an array of objects returned from a post request.

Here's my code in Angular, i only posted pertaining code

`events: any = this.returnArrayOfEvents();`

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
events: this.events
}
 returnArrayOfEvents() {
    let data = { "giornoInizio": 23, "meseInizio": 2, "annoInizio": 2023, "numeroDipendenti": 6,    "turniGiorno": 3, "giorniConsecutivi": 5, "numeroCicli": 2, "giornoInizioSett": 4 }

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8081/turnON/gestioneTurni/generaTurni/list', data)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })    
      
    }
```

this is my console

```
Array(30) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​
0: Object { title: "1", date: "2023-02-23T00:00:00" }
​
1: Object { title: "2", date: "2023-02-23T08:00:00" }
​
2: Object { title: "3", date: "2023-02-23T16:00:00" }
​
3: Object { title: "1", date: "2023-02-24T00:00:00" }
​
4: Object { title: "2", date: "2023-02-24T08:00:00" }
​
5: Object { title: "3", date: "2023-02-24T16:00:00" }
​
6: Object { title: "1", date: "2023-02-25T00:00:00" }
​
7: Object { title: "2", date: "2023-02-25T08:00:00" }
​
8: Object { title: "3", date: "2023-02-25T16:00:00" }
​
9: Object { title: "1", date: "2023-02-26T00:00:00" }
​
10: Object { title: "2", date: "2023-02-26T08:00:00" }
​
11: Object { title: "3", date: "2023-02-26T16:00:00" }
​
12: Object { title: "1", date: "2023-02-27T00:00:00" }
​
13: Object { title: "2", date: "2023-02-27T08:00:00" }
​
14: Object { title: "3", date: "2023-02-27T16:00:00" }
​
15: Object { title: "4", date: "2023-02-28T00:00:00" }
​
16: Object { title: "5", date: "2023-02-28T08:00:00" }
​
17: Object { title: "6", date: "2023-02-28T16:00:00" }
​
18: Object { title: "4", date: "2023-03-1T00:00:00" }
​
19: Object { title: "5", date: "2023-03-1T08:00:00" }
​
20: Object { title: "6", date: "2023-03-1T16:00:00" }
​
21: Object { title: "4", date: "2023-03-2T00:00:00" }
​
22: Object { title: "5", date: "2023-03-2T08:00:00" }
​
23: Object { title: "6", date: "2023-03-2T16:00:00" }
​
24: Object { title: "4", date: "2023-03-3T00:00:00" }
​
25: Object { title: "5", date: "2023-03-3T08:00:00" }
​
26: Object { title: "6", date: "2023-03-3T16:00:00" }
​
27: Object { title: "4", date: "2023-03-4T00:00:00" }
​
28: Object { title: "5", date: "2023-03-4T08:00:00" }
​
29: Object { title: "6", date: "2023-03-4T16:00:00" }
​
length: 30
​
<prototype>: Array []
turni.component.ts:78:16
```

It does render only if i pass it without request like this.
events: any = [{ title: "1", date: "2023-02-23T00:00:00" },{ title: "2", date: "2023-02-23T00:00:00" }]

It does not render if i click "next" and "back" or change timegri

If i add some Logs like this:

```
  firstLog: string = this.logData("pre");
   events: any =  this.returnArrayOfEvents();
  secondLog: any = this.logData("post");
```

the console will be:

```
pre turni.component.ts:61:12
post turni.component.ts:61:12
Array(30) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
```

Maybe that's the problem but how can i console "post" only after the post request ends in typescript language?

Comment: Follow this pattern in fullCalendar to implement a dynamic event feed such as this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Comment: P.S. I think the problem with your current approach is probably because AJAX requests are **asynchronous**, so the event data is passed to the calendar before the POST request has completed. Also, you're not even populating `this.events` in the `subscribe` callback either. The response data isn't returned from the call to .post(), it's made available in the "subscribe" callback in the `res` variable (again, this is because the request is asynchronous, so the main JS thread doesn't wait for it to complete, it just returns immediately).

Comment: You can read more at https://angular.io/guide/http (specifically, https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response is relevant to this case), and there are plenty of tutorials online which also show you how to use it correctly.

Comment: You need to post your solution in the Answers section below. The answer is not part of the question! I rolled back your edit because no-one could have searched for your solution or voted on it, because to the search engine it looks like (part of) a question. Please take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works. The [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) article from the help centre is also relevant.

Comment: To retrieve what you posted previously, check the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75579661/revisions) Thanks.